# in C addresses do not work in functions , why is that?

Tags: c, pass-by-reference, function-declaration

When trying to use a C++ style in C:

```
void square(int &x){
    x = x * x;
};
```

This gets an error.
error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '&' token

i'm most comfortable with c++, but i'm learning C, is there a way to to have adressess in void functions

Tried switching from void -> int, double, char. It only works when i take away the & symbol, but i would like to have an address there. Is there a way to do that?
Should i just use * instead of &, like this :

```
void square(int *x){
    x = (*x) * (*x);
};
```

Comment: Hint: `int*` and `int` are two *very* different things, that's why.

Comment: does c++ don't have pointers?

Comment: "i would like to have an address there" First question: Why? If you want an address, you're going to have to deal with the consequences.

Comment: @Hackaholic C++ has references which don't have this issue.

Comment: too bad for c++ :)

Comment: `void square(int &x)` declares `x` as a *reference*, and that's totally something that C++ has that C does not.  Yes, the way to do it in C is with a pointer `int *x` and explicit dereferences `x = *x * *x` (note you don't need the parentheses).

Answer (score 1):

C language does not have C++ references. You need to use **pointers**

```
void square(int *x)
{
    *x = *x * *x;
}
```

---

Your second code is invalid as you assign a local pointer with integer converted to pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Even in C++ the sign `&` does not denote an address in a declaration. It denotes a reference.

This declaration in C++

```
void square(int &x){
//...
}
```

means that the function accepts its argiment by reference.

In C passing by reference means passing an object indirectly through a pointer to it. So dereferencing a pointer within a function you get a direct access to the original object passed to the function through the pointer.

So this function in C++

```
void square(int &x){
    x = x * x;
}
```

accepts an object of the type `int` by reference.

In C this function

```
void square(int *x){
    *x = *x * *x;
}
```

accepts an object of the type `int` by reference indirectly through a pointer to it.

Pay attention to that the assignment statement in the second function

```
void square(int *x){
    x = (*x) * (*x);
}
```

is incorrect. You are trying to assign an integer expression to a pointer. You have to write

```
    *x = *x * *x;
```

as already shown above. That is you need to change the passed object of the type `int` to the function indirectly through a pointer to it.